# How to change the Font of the text in Birt DEAPI

Tags: java, fonts, birt, birt-deapi

I have created a `Birt` report in which I defined a *Segoeuii* font-family to the text it works fine in windows but when it come of Unix OS it change all the fonts to the *Times new Roman* it is somehow because the font is not present in the Unix file system and `Birt` does not register the font that is not in the file system so we need to register the fonts first so using `FontFactory` I register the font and than set this font in the property but still it displaying *Times new Roman* .
Here is my code.

```
public void testCode() {
    URL font = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("segoeuii.ttf"); // getResourceAsStream("segoeuii.ttf");
    TextItemHandle text = (TextItemHandle) designHandle.findElement("TextProbingAttacks");
    FontFactory.register(font.toString(), "test_font");
    Font myfont = FontFactory.getFont("test_font");
    try {
        text.setProperty("fontFamily", myfont);
    } catch (SemanticException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install fonts in Unix OS.

For example, if you use Ubuntu (linux OS) then

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Restart your eclipse all Microsoft fonts will reflect in your BIRT report perspective

Comment: But after some time I figured out it `Birt` is just showing `Times new Roman` whether the font is in filesystem or not. This problem is with the Unix specifically Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: And registering the font fulfill this need of installing fonts on the system because in some cases in production environment we don't have access of the system.